# How do you get past level 72 of Bubble Bobble Neo

Tags: xbox-live-arcade, bubble-bobble-neo

I've had a little trouble at the beginning of level 72 in Bubble Bobble Neo for XBLA.  I can't seem to get out of the initial position I am in.

I found a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15pKntDl-rs) of someone doing it on the original arcade game, but because of the way the Xbox interprets your movement, it seems impossible to orient your character in the correct position to make it happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see the creator's hint: Pretty tricky but if you stand on the left side and jump, while in the air press dpad right left and blow a bubble you will eventually get it....gotta be quick.

---

The basic idea here is that you can turn fast enough to create a bubble.  In bubble bobble neo bubbles will push you around.  As a result your guy will be pushed back to the side where he can then blow bubble normally.

Comment: You have the right idea but I'm going to add a little something I found out.